# How do i make use of existing empty changelists in p4v eclipse

Tags: eclipse, p4v, review-board

I have modified some files and unfortunately i reverted it by right clicking on change list. I checked with local history. No local history for today's date is found. So my current changelist becomes empty due to my revert. So i recreated all the files and changes. These chages are under in Default Change. How do i move these files to my existing empty changelist or how do i make use of this changelist while sending review through review board?

I googled it but no useful answers found. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **Pending Changelists** view you can drag-and-drop files from one changelist to another. So drag the files from your **Default Change** to the empty one you want them to be in.